# Adjusting Ethernet Frame padding for ARP protocol in windows

Tags: ethernet, arp

Is it possible to configure the count of trailing (padded octets) used for stuffing the ARP messages created by Windows 2008?

NOTE: I hoped, but could not find any info in the [TCPIP_Reg.doc](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/6/c26893a6-46c7-4b5c-b287-830216597340/TCPIP_Reg.doc) from Microsoft.

Comment: I'm just curious why...

Comment: @LatinSuD: As Spiff mentioned minimum 64 octets are required in the ethernet frame that means minimum 42 or 46 octets in the payload for untagged / 802.1q tagged Ethernet frames respectively. I traced down a network issue up to a point that 42 octets are being sent in untagged portion of the LAN for ARP messages...

Comment: Update: Using the ArpUseEtherSNAP registry tweek will change the message to 802.3 standard instead of DIX format, which will increase the message size to 50. But it is not what I want (since the new format is not recognized by some of my devices, specially linux-based ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be. Ethernet requires 64 byte minimum frames. Less would break Ethernet, more would hurt efficiency.